# Histogram, dictionaries, matplotlib?

Tags: python, json, matplotlib, histogram

I need to make a histogram and display statistics on a map. I chose NBA statistics (average speed and number of players with that speed).

Here is my code at the moment:

```
import json

dico = {}

with open("speedata.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)
    for player in data["resultSets"][0]["rowSet"]:
        dico[player[1]] = player


for playerName, playerStats in dico.items():
    print("{%s, %s} -> Average Speed: %s" % (playerName,playerStats[4], playerStats[8]))
```

What I print is e.g.:

```
{DeMar DeRozan, TOR} -> Average Speed: 4.1
{Brandon Knight, MIL} -> Average Speed: 4.2
{Brandon Rush, UTA} -> Average Speed: 4.2
{JJ Redick, LAC} -> Average Speed: 4.6
{Jeremy Tyler, NYK} -> Average Speed: 4.0
{John Salmons, SAC} -> Average Speed: 4.0
{Luke Babbitt, NOP} -> Average Speed: 4.3
{DeAndre Liggins, MIA} -> Average Speed: 3.4
{Chris Kaman, LAL} -> Average Speed: 4.2
{Robert Covington, HOU} -> Average Speed: 4.2
{Dorell Wright, POR} -> Average Speed: 4.2
{Darius Miller, NOP} -> Average Speed: 4.0
```

I would like to get the amount of players with x average speed and then sort them according to their team.

My teacher told me to import some infos from dico, which is a dictionary, to a list; but I can't really see the use.

Any hints? (This is homework)

Comment: Perhaps you should ask *them* for clarification - I've no idea what you're trying to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Check out  [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/). It is a package for statistics which has a convenient container called a DataFrame, with which you can perform stats and plot directly. It is also convenient for reading and writing files directly to/from this container. The syntax takes a bit of getting used to.

Matplotlib syntax is simple whether using pandas or not. It's getting the data into a compatible structure for plotting that requires the most understanding.

Create a list or array of "Average Speed", then use [hist](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=hist#matplotlib.pyplot.hist) to bin & plot the population. Look at the source code example.

Answer (score 0):

Well, using that package wouldn't be the point as i have to use matplotlib myself to understand how it works.